# Is there a way to limit filtering combo box onChange API calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I've implemented a filtering drop down in my application, however, the populated data in this drop down is paginated as it is a huge dataset, so upon each character entry, an API call is fired which isn't very healthy for performance, is there a known approach to address this ?
I'm using react so any if there's any react specific or vanilla js approach would be applicable in my case.

Comment: There's a good article on `throttling` and `debouncing` on `css-tricks.com`, so I suggest you go through those two concepts and implement one of theminto your code, depending on which fits better - https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Comment: @goto1 that was very informative and helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a debounce function, such as the one I use for debouncing a resize event, but it will work the same on your text input change event.

```
/**
 * @description Postpones executing a callback function by a specified time until all the callback's events, occurring in rapid succession, have ended.
 * 
 * @param {number} delay - The time in milliseconds to postpone the callback.
 * @param {Function} callback - The event's callback function.
 * @return {Function} 
 * @public
 * @function
 * 
 * @example
 * 
 * const resizeHandler = (event) => console.log(event);
 * window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(200, resizeHandler));
 * 
 */
const debounce = (delay, callback) => { 

    let timer;

    return (...args) => {

        if (timer) {

            clearTimeout(timer);
        }

        timer = setTimeout(() => {

            callback(...args);
            timer = null;
        }, delay);
    };
};
```

**[EDIT]**  For a complete pair, and just in case anyone finds it useful someday, here's my throttle function.

```
/**
 * @description Delays the frequency of a callback function by a specified time.
 * 
 * @param {number} delay - The time in milliseconds to delay the callback frequency.
 * @param {Function} callback - The event's callback function.
 * @return (Function)
 * @public
 * @function
 * 
 * @example
 * 
 * const mouseMoveHandler = (event) => console.log(event);
 * document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", throttle(200, mouseMoveHandler));
 * 
 */

export const throttle = (delay, callback) => {

    let previousTime = 0;

    return (...args) => {

        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        if (currentTime - previousTime > delay) {

            previousTime = currentTime;

            return callback(...args);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: That's exactly what would solve my problem, I wasn't aware of the concept itself, thank you for the info

Comment: You're welcome.  In case anyone ever finds it useful, I've added my throttle function to the answer, too, as the 2 are often likened to each other, but have slightly different uses.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 one question I had in mind, how can I add a parameter to the debounced method, i.e. what if the resizeHandler method mentioned in the comment in the debouncing method take some args, how can I pass it ?

Comment: @user1712638 there are a few ways to do that, but I would suggest you use the [**.bind()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) Function method.  Any arguments you pass after the `thisArg` will be prepended in the handler's arguments before the`Event` object .  For example, if you wanted to pass some text along with the resize method you could do this:  `const resizeHandler = (greeting, event) => console.log(greeting, event); window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(200, resizeHandler.bind(null, "hello world")));`